# Layout - enlarge multi-value fields using designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, web-part, multiple-values

I changed an Edit Form in Sharepoint (included a script editor web part) to enlarge  multi value fields list boxes (they were to small in width) and it worked (inserted code snippet).

However, if i create a new edit form using sharepoint designer (to set control mode to "Display" in some columns) these multi-value fields are back to small and not enlarged (width) and i don´t know how to do it... sorry not a guru in javascript/html/sharepoint...

Alternate approach to be considered : set control mode to "Display" directly in sharepoint without using designer.

thanks a lot for your help
Nuno

Comment: It sounds like this can easily be set with CSS.  Do you have screenshots of the Display and Edit forms so we can see an example of what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: Hi BigRaj this is the edit Form where the fields are enlarged :

Answer (score 0):

Edit Form built in sharepoint with fields enlarged:

[image: EditForm with fields enlarged]

This is an example of what i want to achieve (set field title as mode display) but fields are kept tiny (this was built in designer):

[image: Edit Form built in designer to set field as display (does not enlarge multivalue fields)]

[image: fields not enlarged in designer]

Comment: i want to edit the form built in sharepoint to allow some fields as display OR to edit the form in designer to enlarge multi value fields Thanks

Comment: code used with success in script editor: <style>
.ms-formtable table.ms-long {
    width:600px !important;
}
.ms-formtable table.ms-long .ms-input>select {
    width:300px !important;
}
</style>

Comment: You also can add your css code on editform via SharePoint designer.

Comment: How can i do that? i have failed trying to do so...